# How to reset MySQL password

Tags: mysql, kubuntu

Have just installed Kubuntu 20.04 and installed mysqlserver and MySQL_secure_installation.  I've somehow got the password wrong and can't access mysql except as root, so

```
xx:~$ sudo mysql
```

gets me into mysql
Have looked at a number of posts but am not getting anywhere.

Any help would be welcome

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: refer this article for reset MYSQL root  password:https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

Answer (score 0):

OK tried:-
:~$ sudo mysql_secure_installation

And was able to change the password. Was using mysql_secure_installation as root before.

Thanks